# need to store a service/factory as a value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I feel I'm stuck in figuring out a resolution to my mvc.NET / angularjs project.

Currently I feel I did a great job by abstracting the view to use a controller that's the the type name of the controller.cs specific class for example:

```
<body ng-controller="@Model.ControllerType.Name">
...
</body>
```

this is the controller

```
superSiteApp.controller("MediaController", ["$scope", "$window", "SubNavFactory", function ($scope, $window, SubNavFactory) {
         ...
});
```

This work seems to work out great, but recently I've been struggling with subnav related items. With one section I basically brute force it (because it isn't a service like so) In this case I'm setting up a factory:

```
var superSiteApp = angular.module('superSiteApp', []);
superSiteApp.factory("SubNavFactory", ["subNavCollectionWrapper", function (subNavCollectionWrapper) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            return subNavCollectionWrapper.get();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Later I push it in here like so:

```
@section AdditionalHeaderLinks
{
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        superSiteApp.value("subNavCollectionWrapper", {
            get: function() {
                return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Menus[1].Links));
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

This part works great, but now I need to do one where I call the api.

So the idea is something like:

```
superSiteApp.service("SubNavFactoryUri", ["$http", "uri", function ($http, uri){
    return $http.get(uri);
}]);
```

This is where I'm lost. In my new View.chtml file, I don't know how to make that connection work.

```
@section AdditionalHeaderLinks
{
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        superSiteApp.value("subNavCollectionWrapper",  /* this is my struggle */);
    </script>
}
```

I can't figure out how to reference the service to pass it in. Yes, I could create a function class on my own, but I thought I'd leverage angularjs.

Maybe the approach is incorrect here, as it's the only thing I could think of doing. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try this 
superSiteApp.value("uri",  "/someurl");
Or maybe I understood you incorrectly.

Comment: I think that's a small portion of it, I would also like to know how to pass this service into it... I'll update showing the angularjs controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it more for a while, I changed things up from using the value() method to supplying a factory. There are a few things I need to work through but it just wound up making sense the more I broke it down.

Here is the idea right now:

```
// same as before, this is for hard coded elements
superSiteApp.factory("SubNavFactory", ["subNavCollectionWrapper", function(subNavCollectionWrapper) {
    return {
        "get": function () {
            return subNavCollectionWrapper.get();
        }
    };
}]);

// This is the idea from above
superSiteApp.service("SubNavServiceUri", ["$http", function($http) {
    return { 
        get: function(uri) { 
            return $http.get(uri); 
        }
    };
}]);


// now we put them together. I'll use the get(action) method to call the item
superSiteApp.factory("SubNavFactories", ["SubNavFactory", "SubNavServiceUri", function(SubNavFactory, SubNavServiceUri) {
        return {
            "ActionName1": {
                "get": function () {
                    return SubNavServiceUri.get("/the/rest/api");
                }
            },
            "ActionName1": SubNavFactory,
            "get" : function(action) {
                return this[action].get();
            }
        };
    }
]);
```